# Getting data to empty array and display search result with giphy API

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ajax, api

I am having trouble getting the page to refresh when i search for a new gif in the app i made that uses the giphy API.Instead of refreshing to display the new search it displays it at the bottom of the previous search so you end up having to scroll all the way down to view the result. Here is my code.

```
function getData() {

 // search box
var input = $("#searchtext").val();

//API request

var xhr = $.get("http://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?q=" + input + 
"+&api_key=KLtIBMAd1cMGVaZ1U3Ba9g5TRJYTsQMy&limit=30");



//promise
xhr.done(function(response) {
console.log("success got data", response);
var jiffs = response.data;

// loop
for (i in jiffs) {
  $('.inner').append("<img src='" + jiffs[i].images.original.url + "' 
 style='height:350px; width:350px;'/>")
}
});
 }
```

here is my html code

```
 <!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Giphy</title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, 
 shrink-to-fit=no">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="giphy.css">
 <!-- jquery  -->
  <script src="js/vendor/modernizr-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" 
 integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" 
 crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script 
src="js/vendor/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
<!--Import Google Icon Font-->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" 
rel="stylesheet">
  <!--Import materialize.css-->
 <link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0- 
rc.2/css/materialize.min.css">
    <!-- cookies -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/js- 
  cookie@2/src/js.cookie.min.js"></script>
  </head>
 <body class="grey darken-4">
 <!-- navbar -->
  <nav>
    <div class="nav-wrapper ">
     <ul id="nav-mobile" class="left hide-on-med-and-down">
      <li><a href="sass.html">Entertainment</a></li>
      <li><a href="badges.html">Sports</a></li>
      <li><a href="collapsible.html">Stickers</a></li>
      <li><a href="collapsible.html">Artists</a></li>
      <button class="btn purple lighten-2">Upload</button>
      <button class="btn purple lighten-2">Create</button>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
<!-- header -->
  <h1 class="white-text center bold">GIPHY</h1>

 <!-- search box -->
<div class="container">
<div class="grey darken-4">
  <input class="white-text" id="searchtext" type="text" 
placeholder="Search..">
  <button class="btn waves-effect purple lighten-2 btn-large " 
id="searchgifs" type="submit" onclick="getData();">Search</button>
</div>
</div>
<div class="inner"></div>




<!-- javascript files -->
  <script src="giphy.js"></script>
  <script src="plugins.js"></script>
    <script 
src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0- 
 rc.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
xhr.done(function(response) {
console.log("success got data", response);
var jiffs = response.data;

// looks like you would want to clear out the current results using at this spot.
$('.inner').html("");

// loop
for (i in jiffs) {
  $('.inner').append("<img src='" + jiffs[i].images.original.url + "' 
 style='height:350px; width:350px;'/>")
}
});
 }
```

Comment: What about using $('.searchresult').remove(); instead of $('.inner').html(""); and add the "<img class='searchresult' ...." ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `empty()` to remove the child elements from `.inner`. If this doesn't work, please post your html.

```
xhr.done(function(response) {
console.log("success got data", response);
var jiffs = response.data;


$('.inner').empty();

// loop
for (i in jiffs) {
  $('.inner').append("<img src='" + jiffs[i].images.original.url + "' 
 style='height:350px; width:350px;'/>")
}
});
 }
```

Comment: I can't see why any of the solutions suggested so far wouldn't work - can you create a jsfiddle?

Comment: Tried the jsfiddle, can't get it to find any search results. What search term should I use?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```js
function getData() {    
    // search box
    var input = $("#searchtext").val();

    //API request

    var xhr = $.get("http://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?q=" + input +
        "+&api_key=KLtIBMAd1cMGVaZ1U3Ba9g5TRJYTsQMy&limit=30");
 
    //promise
    xhr.done(function (response) {
        console.log("success got data", response);
        var jiffs = response.data;
        $('.inner').html('');
        // loop
        for (i in jiffs) {
            $('.inner').append("<img src='" + jiffs[i].images.original.url + "'style='height:350px; width:350px;'/>");
        }
    });
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Giphy</title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="giphy.css">
  <!-- jquery  -->
  <script src="js/vendor/modernizr-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<scriptc src = "js/vendor/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" ><\/script>')</script>
  <!--Import Google Icon Font-->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <!--Import materialize.css-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0- rc.2/css/materialize.min.css">
  <!-- cookies -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/js-cookie@2/src/js.cookie.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body class="grey darken-4">
  <!-- navbar -->
  <nav>
    <div class="nav-wrapper ">
      <ul id="nav-mobile" class="left hide-on-med-and-down">
        <li><a href="sass.html">Entertainment</a></li>
        <li><a href="badges.html">Sports</a></li>
        <li><a href="collapsible.html">Stickers</a></li>
        <li><a href="collapsible.html">Artists</a></li>
        <button class="btn purple lighten-2">Upload</button>
        <button class="btn purple lighten-2">Create</button>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <!-- header -->
  <h1 class="white-text center bold">GIPHY</h1>

  <!-- search box -->
  <div class="container">
    <div class="grey darken-4">
      <input class="white-text" id="searchtext" type="text" placeholder="Search..">
      <button class="btn waves-effect purple lighten-2 btn-large " id="searchgifs" type="submit" onclick="getData();">Search</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="inner"></div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: maryan please try web page refresh with ctrl+f5. Don't forget to clear cache

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace previous result use .html instead of .append. And one more things that you are fetch gif through your url and i think you are getting too much gif which are trying to be rendered and taking long time. But when you request another get request before finishing your previous request your DOM tries to render previous gif while new gif keep coming. So if you receive new gif before previous gif being rendered, that means your new gif will be rendered after previous gif even if you are using .empty or .html because your previous event is still running. 
Be careful while your are playing with DOM element and try not to load all gif at a time use pagination.